# Migrate Schema Registry from VM to k8s with zero downtime

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I want to migrate 3 instances of Schema Registry from VMs (with Kafka leader election - not zookeeper) to docker containers running in kubernetes with zero downtime.

1. Is there any way to check which instances are part of the schema-registry cluster ?
2. Should I expose the k8s instances as services + ingress for each pod ?
3. How to expose schema registry so it can be reachable from outside k8s ?
4. Should I move kafka first into k8s ?

the problem is that kafka can't reach the k8s network/nodes

```
[2023-01-20 13:33:34,778] ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://10.100.102.139:18081/subjects/Alarm/versions (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

5. what env variable to use in order to expose a DNS instead of IP (10.100.102.139), do I need one DNS for each instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which instances are part of the schema-registry cluster

You would compare `kafkastore.bootstrap.servers` + `kafkastore.topic` + `schema.registry.group.id` properties of each instance `schema-registry.properties` (or env-vars for Docker container). If they match, they are the same Registry cluster. The latter two have default values, so may not be set.

> expose the k8s instances as services + ingress for each pod

Depends where you need to access the Registry from. If you don't need external-cluster access, then you don't need an Ingress.

> expose schema registry so it can be reachable from outside k8s

See above. That's what an Ingress does, in combination with a `LoadBalancer` or `ClusterIP` + `NodePort` configuration spec.

> move kafka first into k8s ?

Up to you. That's not a requirement for running the Registry.

> kafka can't reach the k8s network/nodes

The broker doesn't need to communicate with the Registry, only the *clients* do.

> what env variable to use in order to expose a DNS

You wouldn't. Your `IngressController` would be configured to a DNS server, such as ALB IngressController + ExternalDNS w/ AWS. Then you provide that FQDN as `schema.registry.url` in your apps.

I suggest trying a simpler HTTP server first.

> do I need one DNS for each instance ?

Kubernetes does that internally for the pods, but your external DNS address would only be for the Ingress pod. E.g. for nginx IngressController, the DNS entry would point direct traffic at an nginx pod, running a reverse proxy to the other pods.

Comment: Thank for you answer, is there an env variable for schema pods like external_url - what url to expose tu clients. Proxy_host/port does not work

Comment: No. As mentioned, you'd give [the Ingress (which is a reverse proxy)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to clients, not the Registry pod address(es) directly. **Within the cluster**, you use [cluster local dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Comment: Besides, all [config options](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html) are clearly defined, and are set via `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_(PROPERTY_NAME)`... I suggest you just use [their Operator](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/networking/external-access-load-balancer-deploy)

Comment: Really appreciate the responses. But I have an issue: when connecting registry from inside k8s to a Kafka outside, it uses the k8s node ip as hostname, and that node is unreachable from Kafka. So when adding avro schemas to a registry outside k8s, it somehow forwards the request to one registry inside k8s and thus fails because it can't be reached that way. It can be reached through an ingress/elb. How can I advertise that elb when joining the registry cluster?

Comment: Like I said, the broker doesn't need to communicate with the registry. I don't understand how you'd be getting that error. I shared the config above. Did you look at the advertised listeners properties?

Comment: And do you have this value set? So that each instance within the cluster can talk to each other? https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-schema-registry/templates/deployment.yaml#L80

Comment: Yes, i do have that value set. The problem resides in the fact that if you have instances of registry in 2 networks which are not routed directly, they advertise themselves with hostip, and in Kafka they are all master eligible. When pushing new avro schemas, the registry in the same network with Kafka gives that error (because no routing), so it forwards the request to another node part of the cluster. It would be great to advertise another external listener ...

Comment: I guess I'll have to put the ingress:port_instance to host_name and that's it. All registry instances will talk through ingress (not pretty)

Comment: Still not understanding. Why do you have "2 (kubernetes) networks" that cannot talk to each other? That sounds like a VPC/Firewall/Router issue, and not a registry problem. The listeners config does accept multiple bind addresses, but that's internal to the pod, not the external cluster. Requests are forwarded to registry pods, yes, and you can disable master eligibility, via config. Still, the brokers aren't requesting data from the registry. Kafka only stores bytes, bytes which have already been serialized after **clients use the Registry**.